# Return 2D array from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to break a long array into a multiple column (2D) array in my Google Sheets. Here's my function below:

```js
function SPLITARR(data, colNum) {
  if (colNum <= 1) {
    return data;
  }

  var res = [];
  var col = [];
  var i = 0;

  data.forEach(function(el) {
    if (i >= colNum) {
      res.push(col);
      col = [];
      i = 0;
    }

    col.push(el);
    i++;
  });

  res.push(col);
  Logger.log(res); // Debugging purposes.
  return res;
}
```

Sending the following test data:

```
var test = ['alex', 'alecia', 'conrad', 'keenan', 'Beebo', 'jacques', 'jeremy', 'susan', 'jay']
SPLITARR(test, 2);
```

The result that is being logged seems correct:

```
[[alex, alecia], [conrad, keenan], [Beebo, jacques], [jeremy, susan], [jay]]
```

But on Google sheets, nothing shows. The formula displays no errors and fills the expected number of cells, but it fills them with nothing.

**Is there a specific format that 2D arrays need to adhere to in order to be displayed properly?**

Comment: @TheMaster, I think that's incorrect. I just created a dummy function that returns a matrix that is not square/rectangular (I left the 'Jay' on his own) and it still returned successfully. I also updated my function to always return a square/rectangular matrix and it had no effect.

Comment: It must have something to do with the data type. If I add a `.toString()` and store the values as strings in the result array, it works.

Comment: For custom functions, Inputs are 2D  I believe you're making the output a 3D array. How are you calling the function? Quote the formula

Comment: An example of how I'm calling the function: `=SPLITCOL(D18:D23, 2)`

Comment: Where did you setValues()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

`D18:D23` doesn't look like `test` ( `['alex', 'alecia', 'conrad', 'keenan', 'Beebo', 'jacques', 'jeremy', 'susan', 'jay']`). It's a 2D dimensional array. It looks like: `[[D18],[D19],[D20],[D21],[D22],[D23]]`

#### Solution:

Use array methods like `reduce()`, `concat()` and `push()` to mould the array to desired format.

#### Sample Code(for  Multiple Rows in a single column):

```
function SPLITARR(rowData, numberOfCol) {
  return rowData.reduce(function(acc, curr, idx) {
    idx % numberOfCol === 0
      ? acc.push(curr)
      : (acc[acc.length - 1] = acc[acc.length - 1].concat(curr));
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

#### References:

- [Array#methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_instances)

Comment: You are correct, I did not realise using a single column range still returned a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, as mentioned in the comments you should have a rectangular pattern for your 2D array, thus you can't have `[jay]` as your last element, also note that you shouldn't have your names without quotes - instead of `[alex,alecia]` it should be `['alex','alecia']`:

```
function arraytoarray2d() {
var array2d = [];
var arrayx = ['alex', 'alecia', 'conrad', 'keenan', 'Beebo', 'jacques', 'jeremy', 'susan', 'jay']
for (var i in arrayx) {
  if (i % 2 == 0 || i == 0) {
var first = arrayx[i];
var second = arrayx[++i];
if(!second) second = ''; 
array2d.push([first,second]);
}}
}
```

Outputs this:

[image]